# Android studio 1.4 opens new project wizard with empty screen- can't create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, new-project

I downloaded android studio 1.4 and now when i try to open a new project a window opens with "new project wizard" written on the frame of the window, but the window itself is white and empty, and I cannot create a new project.
No errors are showing any where.
Old projects open just fine.
Previous version 1.3.2 worked just fine.

Tried updating, tried uninstalling and installing, tried on different occasions,
tried SDK path- it was correct,to no avail.
please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

For me, When i try to click install SDK tools, that it open a Wizard with white color, What I did means just resize that White wizard. It automatically appeared as a default one.I think this will sure help for you.try this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to re-size the window , right click on the frame and choose size then use the mouse to make the window smaller , I have encountered  same problem before and resolved using this solution